statistical test for paired data with different treatments (ANCOVA? ANOVA? paired difference t-test?)
I have data like this (the data is made up):
Patient    Concentration before   medication    concentration after
1          39.97                  A             37.48
2          18.58                  A              0
3          63.73                  A             63.73
4           7.19                  B              7.19
5           9.31                  B              0
6           9.68                  B              0
7         120.57                  B            123.32

I'm trying to test whether there is a difference in the effects between medication A and B. Which test would I choose?
I have so far found:

ANCOVA
paired difference t-test
Two-Way Repeated Measures ANOVA

It seems that ANOVA/ANCOVA is more sophisticated than the t-test. As far as I can tell, the t-test only works if I want to know if the second set of measurements is different from the first (i.e. if the medication worked). Is this correct? What are the differences between these tests are and which is most suitable for my data?

What kind of a difference are you looking for and how would you measure it?  Those considerations are crucial to determining how to proceed.

In my application, I think one of the medication is more effective than the other in reducing the concentration (of some enzyme in this case)

I'm fairly new to statistics and haven't put enough thought into this I think. In my studies so far, certain tasks always had enough pointers which gave away which test to use. Now this is me hitting reality :D

If you have data or a theory about the effectiveness, use that to formulate a testable hypothesis.  Otherwise you might get more out of exploring these data, which you can readily do by making two scatterplots of the before-after pairs, one for each medication, and studying how they differ and considering whether those differences could be attributed to variation within your population.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

ANOVA, compared to t-test, lets you a) Have more than two groups and b) Have more variables. But, here, from what you posted, you have two groups and one variable, so, that's no more sophisticated.
One note is that, if your measurements are not very reliable, then it is a very good idea to have more than two measurements, otherwise, you can be testing for error in the scoring.
